# Como hospedar o AeroGear?

Tags: jboss, hospedagem, apple-push-notification

Como hospedar o AeroGear, para criar um serviço de push notification. Eu já possuo um host para um pequeno projeto, e gostaria de saber se alguém já usou ou usa o AeroGear e possa orientar como posso hospedar este serviço.

Obrigado.

Comment: Pô, Tiago, como assim "bom" e "obrigado"? Eu já cansei de editar essas coisas fora das suas perguntas (e outros editores também)... Tem certeza que leu o [Tour]?? ... aquela parte sobre "bla bla bla"? . . . . Obrigado aqui é +1 nas respostas úteis. Desculpa o desabafo.

Comment: Acaba sendo parte da mecânica da linguística. E sinceramente, fazer uma pergunta sem relevar um certo sentimento com ela, é como fazer uma pergunta como uma máquina. Entendo as questões de controle do site. Mas acaba sendo automático. Acredito que é apenas uma questão de hábito. E agradeço sinceramente pela ajuda que você e outros vem oferecendo. E não se preocupe. Desabafar é algo normal.

Comment: Acho que precisa ter um servidor dedicado. Com um servidor "compartilhado" não vai ser possível.